How to do pagination for one to many relationship table with Aggregations and Joins?
I have the following SQL query where I join two tables (entity_type and shipment_entity_type) and aggregate the data. The query is designed to compare the number of items in the entity_type table with the total items shipped from the shipment_entity_type table.
Here's the query:
SELECT 
    t1."entityId", 
    t1."typeId", 
    t1."createdAt", 
    t1."itemCount" AS entity_type_items,
    t2.total_items_shipped AS shipped_entity_type_items
FROM 
    public.entity_type t1
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         "entityId", 
         "typeId", 
         SUM("itemsShipped") AS total_items_shipped
     FROM 
         public.shipment_entity_type
     WHERE 
         "deletedAt" IS NULL
     GROUP BY 
         "entityId", "typeId") t2 ON t1."entityId" = t2."entityId" 
                                  AND t1."typeId" = t2."typeId"
WHERE 
    t1."itemCount" <> t2.total_items_shipped;

Now, I would like to add pagination to this query so that I can limit the results and fetch them in pages (e.g., 10 results per page). How can I achieve this?
I'm using PostgreSQL, and I want to handle pagination with LIMIT and OFFSET. What is the best way to modify this query to support pagination?
The problem is I am getting duplicate entityId so If I want to show it on the frontend I will see duplicate data with different typeId.


What does it mean to have a different typeId what does it signify? Why don't you just paginate and order by both entityId and typeId?

I ended up created a new column in the entity_type table. and do the query from there. this way I don't need to compare the itemsShipped on both sides.

Please review [mre]. A query and results without the associated table DDL and corresponding sample data is of limited value. If you have resolved the issue, then please post your solution as an answer so that others might benefit. A vague comment about adding a column is of no use to anyone. Having additional context makes it easier for others to identify possible improvements to the described approach.

I have a proposition for the actual SQL code.
Using CTEs (Common Table Expressions).
New code:
WITH aggregated_shipment AS (
    SELECT 
        "entityId", 
        "typeId", 
        SUM("itemsShipped") AS total_items_shipped
    FROM 
        public.shipment_entity_type
    WHERE 
        "deletedAt" IS NULL
    GROUP BY 
        "entityId", "typeId"
),
comparison_result AS (
    SELECT 
        t1."entityId", 
        t1."typeId", 
        t1."createdAt", 
        t1."itemCount" AS entity_type_items,
        t2.total_items_shipped AS shipped_entity_type_items
    FROM 
        public.entity_type t1
    JOIN 
        aggregated_shipment t2 
    ON 
        t1."entityId" = t2."entityId" 
        AND t1."typeId" = t2."typeId"
    WHERE 
        t1."itemCount" <> t2.total_items_shipped
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cr."entityId") 
    cr."entityId",
    cr."typeId",
    cr."createdAt",
    cr."entity_type_items",
    cr."shipped_entity_type_items"
FROM 
    comparison_result cr
ORDER BY 
    cr."entityId", cr."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;

Walk-through:

The sub query aggregated_shipment will aggregates data from the shipment_entity_type table while the comparison_result combines entity_type and aggregated_shipment identifying rows where itemCount differs from the shipped items.
Now pagination is done by LIMIT {items size} AND OFFSET {items pages}, to fetch more data with the same size/limit.
Using sql DISTINCT ON will help you eliminating duplicate entityId values while prioritizing rows based on the createdAt timestamp.


Thank you. I actually did this previously and the query was so slow. in our database there are millions of rows and I found that CTE creates a separate table so that's why it was slow. do you know anything about this?

Since the OP didn't provide sample data and expected output, it's impossible to know what query will satisfy the requirements. Ignoring all but one row for each entityId is likely not what the OP intended.
